# Draft-js: auto line break

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rich-text-editor, draftjs

I'm trying to implement an editor using facebook's **`Draft-JS`** framework which will be limited to a 50 characters line.

I don't want the lines to break using css, I want them to really break into separate blocks when reaching this 50 characters limit.

The line break should happen at the last space before the word exceeding the 50th character (similar to `word-wrap: break-word` in css).

Surely, I need the selection to stay at the end of the new line.

I'm not sure where to start with this. Any ideas?

- I've created a draft-js codepen with a preview of the current editorState for easy start, just not sure where to start: https://codepen.io/adamtal/pen/pbqVrL?editors=0010

**Update:**
As a response to `Jiang YD`'s answer, I don't think it's a good idea to take the text from the end of the block and create a new block with it.. Not sure how well the formatting state will be kept. I think the solution should use [Modifier.splitBlock](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/api-reference-modifier.html#splitblock) with some selection manipulation maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this same issue where I had a split a block and had to give the new split block some metadata.

Getting the key of the next block that's been created after the split was the tricky part. Here's how I got it done.

```
const selection = editorState.getSelection();
let contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();

contentState = Modifier.splitBlock(contentState, selection);

const currentBlock = contentState.getBlockForKey(selection.getEndKey());
const nextBlock = contentState
  .getBlockMap()
  .toSeq()
  .skipUntil(function(v) {
    return v === currentBlock;
  })
  .rest()
  .first();

const nextBlockKey = nextBlock.getKey();

const nextBlockEmptySelection = new SelectionState({
  anchorKey: nextBlockKey,
  anchorOffset: 0,
  focusKey: nextBlockKey,
  focusOffset: 0
});

contentState = Modifier.setBlockData(
  contentState,
  nextBlockEmptySelection,
  Map()
    .set("data1", "Hello this is block data")
    .set("data2", 3)
);
```